# How can I reduce Python's Exception raising output?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I have this line of Python code:

```
raise ValueError(f"Invalid input '{number}'")
```

When it raises an exception I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/snowcrash/Code/Python/mycode/mycode.py", line 8, in __init__
    raise ValueError(f"Invalid input '{number}'")
ValueError: Invalid input 'a1b2c3'
```

however I'd prefer to get:

```
File "/home/snowcrash/Code/Python/mycode/mycode.py", line 8, in __init__
  ValueError: Invalid input 'a1b2c3'
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I'd say, catch the exception and format your own error message. If you can't recover from that point, terminate, else recover and continue. The correctness of a script or program should never rely on the ability of the execution environment to catch exceptions.

Comment: The point of tracebacks is to provide as much information as feasible *for debugging*. Do you actually want to provide debugging information, or just inform a user of wrong input? What's your criteria for collapsing calls? Say your code does not ``raise`` directly but calls another function that eventually ``raise``s, do you also want to suppress your code that and just show some innards of an implementation detail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sys.excepthook(type, value, traceback)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) is the function that does the printing when an exception is raised. You can write your own function (with a similar signature) and simply replace it with:

`sys.excepthook = myfunction`

You can do whatever you want in this function. You may log to files, or print some information about the state of the program when the exception occurred, for example. You may even arrange for different things to happen depending on the type of exception.

However if all you want to do is format your traceback message, lots of convenient stuff is already provided for you. You can dig into the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_tb) docs for the details, but here is an example that produces roughly the output you want:

```
import sys, traceback


def myhook(type, value, tb):
    trace = traceback.format_tb(tb, limit=1)
    trace = trace[0].split("\n")[0]
    exc = traceback.format_exception_only(type, value)[0]
    print(trace + "\n" + exc)


sys.excepthook = myhook

number = "a1b2c3"
raise ValueError(f"Invalid input {number}")
```

which produces an output of:

```
  File "scratch/so.py", line 14, in <module>
ValueError: Invalid input a1b2c3
```

Note especially the use of `traceback.format_tb` with `limit=1`, to limit the stack trace output. There are a bunch of these functions in the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#module-traceback) module.